# Why does zero padding in my CSS create 'false' margin?

Tags: html, css

I've run into this in the past, but I've usually been able to design around the issue -- usually by setting the top-margin on the first P or H1 tag to zero manually  (Didn't work this time ).

Why am I getting a 'false' margin when I set my padding/margin to 0PX?  If I give the wrap div even one PX padding, it auto-magically corrects the issue and everything looks nice, if I don't I get a white space at the top which simply doesn't make any sense.  Why does changing the padding effect the margin of the contained div?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rE9up/)

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [Margin Collapse](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing). There are [many tutorials](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) to be found once you know this name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `overflow: hidden;` does the magic.

```
#wrap
{
    width:1024px;
    height:748px;
    background:#000;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```